# XQuery with SQLServer finding nodes with a wildcard

Tags: sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql

I have an XML document similar to below with multiple links stored in a SQLServer database

```
<Pop_Up>
    <Link1_Url />
    <Link2_Url />
    <Link3_Url>Some URL</Link3_Url>
</Pop_Up>
```

I'm trying to extract all the Links using:

```
select t.Data_xml.value('(/Pop_Up/Link*_Url)[1]','varchar(500)') as link
from TableName t
```

But it seems like the wildcard `*` is not allowed. Are there any alternative ways I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate through the nodes and get their value, while the name corresponds to your criteria, like:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<Pop_Up>
    <Link1_Url />
    <Link2_Url />
    <Link3_Url>Some URL</Link3_Url>
</Pop_Up>'

SELECT 
    t2.c2.value('.', 'varchar(500)') linkValue,
    t2.c2.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as linkKey
FROM @xml.nodes('//Pop_Up') t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('*') AS t2(c2)
WHERE t2.c2.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') LIKE 'Link%_Url'
```

Which results in:

```
linkValue   linkKey
            Link1_Url
            Link2_Url
Some URL    Link3_Url
```